# Symbolic ticks on ListPlot

Tags: plotting, ticks, education

I tried to change the name of ticks of the y axis on a `ListPlot` with symbolic names with the following code (`0.2` with `a`, `0.4` with `b`...):

```
ListPlot[{{0, 0}, {0.125, 0.125}, {0.25, 0.25}, {0.375, 0.375}, {0.5, 
   0.5}, {0.625, 0.625}, {0.75, 0.75}}, InterpolationOrder -> 0, 
 Joined -> True, PlotRange -> {{0, 0.8}, {0, 0.8}}, 
 FrameTicks -> {{{0.125, "a"}, {0.25, "b"}, {0.375, "c"}}, Automatic, 
   Automatic, Automatic}, Frame -> True]
```

but it does not work. How can I get the desired result?

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: add the option `Frame->True` or  use `Ticks -> {{{0.2, "a"}, {0.4, "b"}, {0.6, "c"}}, Automatic}`

Comment: Hello @kglr I edited my question adding frame->true...it still doesn't work.

Comment: with `Frame->True`, `FrameTicks -> {{ Automatic, Automatic },{{{0.125, "a"}, {0.25, "b"}, {0.375, "c"}}, Automatic}}` should work

Comment: @kglr I tried also to inverte frame->true and frametricks as you mentioned, nut nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ListPlot[{{0, 0}, {0.125, 0.125}, {0.25, 0.25}, {0.375, 0.375}, {0.5, 0.5},
  {0.625, 0.625}, {0.75, 0.75}}, 
  InterpolationOrder -> 0, 
  Joined -> True, PlotRange -> {{0, 0.8}, {0, 0.8}}, 
  Frame -> True,
  FrameTicks -> {{ Automatic, Automatic }, 
    {{{0.125, "a"}, {0.25, "b"}, {0.375, "c"}}, Automatic}}]
```

[image]

Alternatively, remove `Frame->True` and `FrameTicks -> ...` and add the option

```
Ticks -> {{{0.125, "a"}, {0.25, "b"}, {0.375, "c"}}, Automatic}
```

[image]

```
 $Version
```

> "11.3.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)"

Comment: Excellent solution @kglr. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Gennaro, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.